# PostgreSQL Split Single Column Values to Multiple Columns Based on Pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas

I am using SAS EG against a Postgres database with explicit pass-through SQL. I have a messy table that was given to me that I need to "clean up" for the end-user.  One of the columns (varchar255) in the table has multiple date values smashed together.  Most of the values just have one date value (i.e. 10/11/2018) but a few look like this (8/11/201810/6/2019).  I need to split these out but there is no delimiter in which to split other than maybe a pattern but even then it's variable length so I don't know how to do it.  Basically, the first date in the sequence can be (1-2 number month/1-2 number day/4 number year) followed by they next date.  How can I split these and separate them by a delimiter so that I can then perform a split_to_array, count the highest number of separate values in the array and then make the appropriate number of new columns to accommodate the separate dates? Ordinarily, I would provide a code example but in this case I don't even know where to start to parse these out.

**Original Value Example:**

```
row1 6/4/2017
row2 8/11/201810/6/2019
row3 10/16/20134/12/201812/18/2019
```

**Desired Value Example:**

```
row1 6/4/2017
row2 8/11/2018, 10/6/2019
row3 10/16/2013, 4/12/2018, 12/18/2019
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This feels like a bad design to me.  Not sufficiently normalized.

Comment: Yes, the table provided to us was in terrible condition.  I've been cleaning it up for a week now!

Comment: Needs to become a one-to-many relationship - two tables, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make regular expression that matches your dates.  This works in SAS. Note that it adds an extra comma, but you could either remove that, figure out how to make a more complex regex, or just ignore the extra comma.

```
WANT=prxchange('s/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/$1,/',-1,HAVE);
```

Looks like Postgres has a regex_replace() function, so something like this should work

```
regexp_replace(HAVE,'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})','\1,','g') as WANT
```

Comment: You're right!  This does exactly what I want it too...in SAS!  If I could find an equivalent feature to run it in-database then I would be on the home stretch.  This gives me a great place to start though in looking for an equivalent function!  Otherwise, I'll just process this one column in SAS and then match back to the other columns to make a final table.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is ultimately what I came back to and used.  It was perfect.  I followed this with using a max array function to get the highest number of days listed in all the rows.  Then used that to determine how many new columns I would need and used split_part to separate each part into the new columns.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use the PostgreSQL function `regexp_match`.

From PostgreSQL docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

> In the common case where you just want the whole matching substring or NULL for no match, write something like
>
> `SELECT (regexp_match('foobarbequebaz', 'bar.*que'))[1];`
> `regexp_match`
> `--------------`
> `barbeque`

Might need a couple select expressions, where in the regex pattern has more and more date patterns before the to be captured date pattern group, as you try to pull out more and more datestrings.

```
regexp_match(mashed, '(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})`) as datestring1,
regexp_match(mashed,  '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})`) as datestring2,
etc …
```